# Wiping my Hard Drive and dualbooting Ubuntu 13

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, alienware

I've searched far and wide, but still haven't found a way to do what I want;

I want to set up a GNU GRUB dualboot with windows 7 and ubuntu 13. As of now, I am running a;

- Alienware M15X Purchased September 14 2010
- Intel Core i7 CPU Q740 @ 1.73GHz 1.73GHz
- 6GB of RAM
- 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5800 Series

I want to wipe everything on my desktop other than files necessary for windows to still perform. I want no information left, other than windows 7 in a running state. After that, I'll add Ubuntu as a dual-boot using GNU GRUB. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your best course of action: you make a recovery disk in Windows, boot off of it, and re-install, which will wipe your hard drive and give you a fresh install. Afterwards, make an Ubuntu boot disk and select "Boot alongside Windows 7" at installation. Then just follow the instructions on screen from there on out.

Answer (score 0):

The files in Windows you can uninstall via Windows control panel and delete any folders that you don't need. Then for Ubuntu [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows) has all the answers for a windows user not familar with Ubuntu.